# Is this Eberron home-brew Shifter sub-race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, eberron

Looking to get the hive-mind's feedback on the following homebrew Shifter sub race:

> ## **Brightwit**
>
> Quick of mind as well as body, brightwit shifters are renowned for their cunning. Fox ancestry is common, but so is rat, rabbit, snake, or even raven.
>
> **Ability Score Increase.** Your Intelligence score increases by 2, and your Dexterity score increases by 1.
>
> **Sharp Eyes.** You have proficiency with the Investigation skill.
>
> **Shifting Feature.** While shifted, you can take two reactions per round, instead of one.

Comment: Hi Brightwit, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. While we do homebrew review, we don't do questions that are just seeking arbitrary feedback: see [what kinds of questions should I avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) from our [help]. We focus on resolving specific practical problems, so our homebrew review is focused on that too. If you just want general response I suggest you ask on a forum: we'd recommend [one of these from our curated list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/1204).

Comment: The title asks about balance, and although it says feedback in the question it is pretty clearly asking for balance concerns.

Comment: This question can be valid for our site, it just needs a bit of cleaning up. Take a look at [How to write a good homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/48759) for some information. Adding some details on what you are trying to achieve and how you made it and specifically what kind of feedback you are looking for should get your question reopened. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

#### Multiple reactions is probably unbalanced.

*Dungeon Master's Guide*, p.263, recommends against allowing multiple reactions per round:

> Beware of adding anything to your game that allows a character to concentrate on more than one effect at a time, **use more than one reaction** or bonus action per round, or attune to more than three magic items at a time. Rules and game elements that override the rules for concentration, reactions, bonus actions, and magic item attunement can seriously unbalance or overcomplicate your game.